# Generics & Types

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am using generics in a certain data structure. I have to store `int x`, `int y`, and `Value value`, where `value` is the generic type.

I am trying to group all those in one object called `NodeData` and then in another class, create an ArrayList of `NodeData`'s, (so each element in the array list will include hold an x, y and value.

My `NodeData` is as follows:

```
public class NodeData<Value> {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Value value;
```

In another class, the array list instantiated as follows: `ArrayList<NodeData> items = new ArrayList<NodeData>();`.

I am getting an error for the array list which says: `NodeData is a raw type. References to NodeData<Value> should be parametrized.` Why is that? `NodeData` is already parametrized as `NodeData<Value>`.

Thanks

Comment: when you do NodeData<Value> it is assumed you will be substituting some real class for Value. The way you have defined it Value can be of any type whatsoever which is probably not what you want.

Comment: You're not getting an error but rather a ***warning***, and that's a big difference. What you're doing is not safe, but can potentially work if you take care. I advise you to follow duffymo's advice though as this is what generics are for -- to allow compile time type-checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in your array declaration.  Try it like this:

```
List<NodeData<Foo>> list = new ArrayList<NodeData<Foo>>();
```

where `Foo` is the `Value` type you want for that instance.

Answer (score 2):

In the other class, You'll have to specify the type you intend to use in place of the generic type `Value`

eg.

```
ArrayList<NodeData<String>> items = new ArrayList<NodeData<String>>();.
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It says `Bound mismatch: The type Value is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <Value extends Comparable<? super Value>> of the type NodeData<Value>` Why is that? I don't understand

Comment: @Nayefc I had missed a `>` at the end. It's fixed now.

Comment: That wasn't the issue I haven't copied and pasted, I added it myself. It just disappeared on its own now, maybe took time for my IDE to realize that. Works now thanks.